# White box input stream for creating test scenarios

Tags: unit-testing, scala, stream

I need to test a specialized input stream class that takes input from a TCP/IP network connection. I particularly need to ensure that the blocking and availability behavior is correct.

To help me with this, I wrote this "white box" input stream so that test scenarios can provide the necessary test conditions to exercise the code being tested.

WhiteBoxInputStream.scala

```
import java.io.InputStream

import scala.collection.mutable

/**
 * A stream to be used in test scenarios to create specific conditions.
 */
class WhiteBoxInputStream extends InputStream {

  private var current: Array[Byte] = null
  private var pos: Int = -1

  private var isEOF: Boolean = false
  private val data = new mutable.Queue[Array[Byte]]

  def this(someData: Array[Byte]) {
    this()

    queueData(someData)
  }

  override def read(): Int = {
    if (current != null) doRead()
    else if (isEOF) -1
    else {
      var notReady = true

      while (notReady) {
        Thread.sleep(10)
        if (current != null) notReady = false
      }

      doRead()
    }
  }

  def doRead(): Int = {
    val result = current(pos)
    incrementPos()
    result
  }

  override def available(): Int = {
    this.synchronized {
      if (current == null) 0
      else data.foldLeft(current.length - pos)((a, b) => a + b.length)
    }
  }

  def queueData(someData: Array[Byte]): Unit = {
    if (isEOF) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Can't add more data to stream in End Of File state.")
    }

    if (current == null) {
      current = someData
      pos = 0
    }
    else this.synchronized{
      data.enqueue(someData)
    }
  }

  def markEOF(): Unit = {
    isEOF = true
  }

  private def incrementPos(): Unit = {
    pos += 1
    if (pos >= current.length) {
      current = null
      pos = -1

      dequeueData()
    }
  }

  private def dequeueData(): Unit = {
    if (data.nonEmpty) {
      this.synchronized
      {
        current = data.dequeue()
        pos = 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

WhiteBoxInputStreamTest.scala

```
import edu.stsci.efl.ml.{EFLContext, ModuleLoader}
import edu.stsci.efl.services.LoggerFactoryService
import edu.stsci.util.WhiteBoxInputStreamTest._

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, BeforeAndAfter, FunSuite}
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.slf4j.Logger

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class WhiteBoxInputStreamTest extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter with Matchers {
  var context: EFLContext = null
  var logger: Logger = null

  before {
    ModuleLoader.shutdown()
    Thread.sleep(1000)

    val resourceURL = getClass.getResource("genericManifest.xml")
    resourceURL should not be (null)
    ModuleLoader.initialize(resourceURL)

    context = ModuleLoader.getDefaultContext

    logger = {
      val service = context.findRequiredService(classOf[LoggerFactoryService])
      service.getLogger(getClass.getName)
    }
  }

  test("simple case") {
    val testObject = new WhiteBoxInputStream(Array[Byte](A, B))
    testObject.markEOF()

    val a = testObject.read()
    a should be(A)

    val b = testObject.read()
    b should be(B)

    val eof = testObject.read()
    eof should be(EOF)
  }

  test("two block") {
    val testObject = new WhiteBoxInputStream(Array[Byte](A))
    testObject.queueData(Array[Byte](B))

    val a = testObject.read()
    a should be (A)

    val b = testObject.read()
    b should be (B)
  }

  test("blocking read") {
    val testObject = new WhiteBoxInputStream(Array[Byte](A))
    val d = new DataThread(logger, testObject)

    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val a = testObject.read()
    a should be (A)

    d.start()

    val b = testObject.read()
    b should be (B)

    val stop = System.currentTimeMillis()
    // if the read blocked properly then there should be a delay here
    (stop - start) should be > (900l)
  }

  test("available") {
    val testObject = new WhiteBoxInputStream(Array[Byte](A, B))

    testObject.available() should be(2)

    testObject.queueData(Array[Byte](A))

    testObject.available() should be(3)

    testObject.read()

    testObject.available() should be(2)

    testObject.read()

    testObject.available() should be(1)

    testObject.read()

    testObject.available() should be(0)
  }
}

class DataThread(logger: Logger, testObject: WhiteBoxInputStream) extends Thread {
  override def run(): Unit = {
    logger.trace("[DataThread.run] enter.")

    Thread.sleep(1000)
    testObject.queueData(Array[Byte](B))
    logger.trace("[DataThread.run] complete.")
  }
}

object WhiteBoxInputStreamTest {
  val A = 'a'.toByte
  val B = 'b'.toByte

  val EOF = -1
}
```

I am particularly interested in criticism of my Scala form.

Comment: Whoah, this code is pretty. Nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) instead and get rid of some of those synchronized blocks.